# How do i wait for a page to load after a form submits in Webdriver. I am using firefox driver

Tags: webdriver

I am trying to automate a test case where i submit the form by clicking on an image.

After the page reloads i am not able to interact with any element on the webpage

I am using java , firefox driver.

The code gets stuck and is not able to identify the element at all.

Is there any wait mechanism with webdriver like there is with QTP , selenium ?

Answer (score 5):

2 years later, ruby implementation:

```ruby
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10)
wait.util {
  @driver.execute_script("return document.readyState;") == "complete" 
}
```

Comment: Cool. But the current version does handle page transition load very well!

Comment: @ThiagoFMacedo I can't speak for Linux but it is not my experience that it handles it well on Windows. We do something similar allenhwkim suggested.

Comment: There's a typo there. It should be `wait.until`, not util.

Answer (score 3):

Just use [FluentWait](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html) class:

```
/**
 * An implementation of the {@link Wait} interface that may have its timeout
 * and polling interval configured on the fly.
 *
 * <p>Each FluentWait instance defines the maximum amount of time to wait for
 * a condition, as well as the frequency with which to check the condition.
 * Furthermore, the user may configure the wait to ignore specific types of
 * exceptions whilst waiting, such as
 * {@link org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException NoSuchElementExceptions}
 * when searching for an element on the page.
 *
 * <p>Sample usage:
 * <code><pre>
 *   // Waiting 30 seconds for an element to be present on the page, checking
 *   // for its presence once every 5 seconds.
 *   Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
 *       .withTimeout(30, SECONDS)
 *       .pollingEvery(5, SECONDS)
 *       .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
 *
 *   WebElement foo = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
 *     public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
 *       return driver.findElement(By.id("foo"));
 *     }
 *   });
 *
```

or [WebDriverWait](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html).

Comment: Is this a new class?  I've got 2.39 (of the c# bindings) and it doesnt seem to be there.  What dll does this come from?  Maybe I'm missing one

Answer (score 0):

I think with  selenium 2, you don't need to wait after a form submit using Firefox webdriver.

```
     element.sendKeys("34344343");
     webDriver.findElement(By.id("searchSubmitButton")).click();

WebElement columnInPostedPage =  webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='content']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]")); //
```

If content is loaded by javascript after the page is loaded, you can do something like this for the content

```
     query.submit();

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000;
    while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {
        WebElement result = webDriver.findElement(By.id("content"));
        if (result.isDisplayed()) {
          break;
        }
        //Thread.sleep(1000);
    }        

     WebElement columnInPostedPage =  webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='content']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]")); //
```

Comment: Whether Selenium 2 will wait after the `click()` depends on how the page is loaded.

Comment: I think an exception will throw you out of the time loop.  I don't think this would work.  You need to use a WebDriverWait with the .ignoring method.

Answer (score -2):

http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.0/doc/java/

waitForpageLoad()

Comment: I guess waitForPageLoad is used when you are using selenium RC.  

whats the case with Webdriver ? I am using Firefox driver ....

i did some try and error and it seems that there is no need to write anything whenever we submit a form .

can someone please comment

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720325/selenium-webdriver-wait-for-complex-page-with-javascript-to-load

Answer (score -2):

```
for (int second = 0;; second++) {
            if (second >= 60) fail("timeout");
            try { if (isElementPresent(By.linkText("element"))) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
```

Comment: -1: Webdriver has its methods for implicitly and explicitly waiting: [here](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits)

Comment: Thnx for the answer. Will learn more about selenium in the future