# What exactly does driver.get() do?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

The WebDriver [documentation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#selenium-webdriver-api-commands-and-operations) states the following for the `driver.get()` operation:

> Dependent on several factors, including the OS/Browser combination,
>   WebDriver may or may not wait for the page to load. In some
>   circumstances, WebDriver may return control before the page has
>   finished, or even started, loading

Can anyone explain under what circumstances WebDriver returns control before the page has finished, or even started, loading?

Comment: BTW, I like your name :)

Comment: Hi @Saifur. Let's get in touch via form given in my profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a simple form, `.get()` navigates you to a URL.

> Can anyone explain under what circumstances WebDriver returns control
>   before the page has finished, or even started, loading?

This kind of situation is pretty common nowadays - there are more and more pages out there that **load asynchronously**. Selenium would not wait for responses to outstanding AJAX requests or currently running scripts which can cause different errors while trying to access elements that are not present in DOM, or are not yet visible, or not yet having the desired data.

And this is, by the way, one of the reasons for the [`protractor` package](https://github.com/angular/protractor) to exist specifically for AngularJS application testing - it listens for an angular to signal "okay, I'm done with this page".

There are multiple ways to *wait for a page to load*:

- increase ["Page load timeout"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15127377/771848) (not quite reliable)
- [wait for a DOM `readyState` to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11356234/771848)
- [explicitly wait for a specific element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7811812/771848) to be present in DOM or visible - this approach is the most common and the most reliable

Here is a [perfect answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15136386/771848) that should help in clearing things up.

Also see related topics with some great explanations of the problem:

- [Wait for page load in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868439/wait-for-page-load-in-selenium)
- [How I can check whether a page is loaded completely or not in web driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001030/how-i-can-check-whether-page-is-loaded-completely-or-not-in-web-driver/11002061#11002061)
- [Selenium WebDriver : Wait for complex page with JavaScript(JS) to load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720325/selenium-webdriver-wait-for-complex-page-with-javascriptjs-to-load/10726369#10726369)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the WebDriver you are using.

In almost every WebDriver, control is given after document loaded. This means there is a possibility a onDocumentReady JavaScript callback is not yet finished.

To circumvent this, you can use a WebDriverWait or a FluentWait with a suitable predicate.

A Thread.sleep() is also possible, but a rather dirty way!

Comment: When you say "control is given after document loaded", how does WebDriver define "document loaded"?

Comment: Depends on the driver. You can have a look at GrepCode for this. Here is an example of HtmlUnitDriver: http://grepcode.com/search/usages?type=method&id=repo1.maven.org%24maven2@net.sourceforge.htmlunit%24htmlunit@2.15@com%24gargoylesoftware%24htmlunit@WebConnection@getResponse%28com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebRequest%29&k=uttp://grepcode.com/search/usages?type=method&id=repo1.maven.org%24maven2@net.sourceforge.htmlunit%24htmlunit@2.15@com%24gargoylesoftware%24htmlunit@WebConnection@getResponse%28com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebRequest%29&k=u