# Python Selenium Scrape Hidden Data

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the following page (just page 1 for the purpose of this question):

https://www.sportstats.ca/display-results.xhtml?raceid=4886

I can use Selinium to grab the source then parse it, but not all of the data that I'm looking for is in the source. Some of it needs to be found by clicking on elements.

For example, for the first person I can get all the visible fields from the source. But if you click the +, there is more data I'd like to scrape. For example, the "Chip Time" (01:15:29.9), and also the City (Oakville) that pops up on the right after clicking the + for a person.

I don't know how to identify the element that needs to be clicked to expand the +, then even after clicking it, I don't know how to find the values I'm looking for.

Any tips would be great.

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Comment: Try to use ``$(".ui-row-toggler.ui-icon.ui-icon-circle-triangle-e").click()`` in Selenium to get all the ``+`` button clicked. Then you can analysis the generated page like you used to.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample code for your requirement. This code is base on python , selenium with crome exe file.

```
            from selenium import webdriver
            from lxml.html import tostring,fromstring
            import time
            import csv

            myfile = open('demo_detail.csv', 'wb')
            wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
            driver=webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe')
            csv_heading=["","","BIB","NAME","CATEGORY","RANK","GENDER PLACE","CAT. PLACE","GUN TIME","SPLIT NAME","SPLIT DISTANCE","SPLIT TIME","PACE","DISTANCE","RACE TIME","OVERALL (/814)","GENDER (/431)","CATEGORY (/38)","TIME OF DAY"]
            wr.writerow(csv_heading)
            count=0
            try:
                url="https://www.sportstats.ca/display-results.xhtml?raceid=4886"
                driver.get(url)
                table_tr=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class='results overview-result']/tbody/tr[@role='row']")
                for tr in table_tr:
                    lst=[]
                    count=count+1
                    table_td=tr.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")
                    for td in table_td:
                        lst.append(td.text)

                    table_td[1].find_element_by_tag_name("div").click()
                    time.sleep(5)
                    table=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='ui-datatable ui-widget']")
                    for demo_tr in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[@class='ui-expanded-row-content ui-widget-content view-details']/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr"):
                        for demo_td in demo_tr.find_elements_by_tag_name("td"):
                            lst.append(demo_td.text)
                    wr.writerow(lst)
                    table_td[1].find_element_by_tag_name("div").click()
                    time.sleep(5)
                    print count
                time.sleep(5)
                driver.quit()
            except Exception as e:
                print e
                driver.quit()
```