# WebDriver: Waiting for 'JS Popup Screen' to Load without using Thread.sleep()

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Unable to click on Radio Buttons, once the popup has loaded

*Please note i have raised a question in the past but i want to avoid using Thread.sleep
 [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38528920/webdriver-wait-untilexpectedconditions-elementtobeclickable-only-works-when/38563125#38563125*):

Scenario (Successful)
1. If i access any hut directly via the following [URL](https://www.pizzahut.co.uk/Store/FindAHut?type=delivery&postcode=OX14%205DR&storeid=8127):  
2. Iam successfully able to click on the link which is selecting the radio button 'Order for later'

Scenario (Not Successful)
 1. If i access the Pizza Hut [URL](https://www.pizzahut.co.uk/): 
 2. Click Pizza Button
 3. Click any 'Pizza Type' *Start your Order* button
 4. When the localisation page appears > type postcode 'AL1 2PS' > click find a hut
 5. My Script is unable to click on the 'Order for Later' radio button 
 6. But in the Successful scenario iam able to click on the link?
 7. I have tried many waits and custom waits, js waits but the only time Iam successfully able to click on the link is using `Thread.sleep(`)

Please could anybody advice on a solution to the problem?

Many thanks for you help

Comment: What version of Selenium are you using? Have you tried upgrading to latest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post any code so I'm not sure what all you have tried. I wrote the code below and it works.

```
String pizzaType = "Hawaiian"; // the pizza type from the Pizza menu
String postcode = "AL1 2PS";
String url = "https://www.pizzahut.co.uk/";
driver.get(url);
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Pizza")).click(); // click Pizza menu
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[text()='" + pizzaType + "']/../../../..//button")).click(); // click a pizza type specified by pizzaType
driver.findElement(By.id("ajax-postcode-txt")).sendKeys(postcode); // enter a postcode
driver.findElement(By.id("get-store-btn")).click(); // click "Find a Hut"
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[data-value='later']")).click(); // click "Order for later"
```

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark it as accepted and if you found it useful (or any answer for that matter) please upvote it.