# How to identify any jQuery components are active on current web page using webDriver?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am currently trying to automate web page contains few js and jQuery implementations using **selenium WebDriver**. I have noticed few posts says about implementing the code to wait for page load completely.

```
ExpectedCondition<Boolean> jQueryLoad = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            try {
                return ((Long) executeJavaScript("return jQuery.active") == 0);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    };
```

But I am unable to solve'**undefined type error**' thrown by the use of **'executeJavaScript'**. Can someone guide me which library I am missing? or How to work with this code.

Comment: Appreciate those who devote with **comments**. I have put effort to understand unclear or unwanted posts/code posted in StackOverflow when  I confront with.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method `executeJavaScript`, there is one method `executeScript` which you can use to execute your javascript but for that you have to cast your webdriver instance into `JavascriptExecutor`. Below is the code for your reference:-

Replace your return statement with following:-

```
((long)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return jQuery.active") == 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this. But please have a look at this [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720325/selenium-webdriver-wait-for-complex-page-with-javascriptjs-to-load). I tried by casting Driver instance to JavaScriptExecutor. 'return ((long)js.executeScript("return jQuery.active") == 0);'.

Comment: which selenium version jar are you using?

Comment: I am using 'selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1' with JDK 1.8.

Comment: check if you have guava.jar in your build path?

Comment: I have added 'guava.jar' in my classpath before posted in StackOverflow. But that didn't resolve my problem.