# Wait for javascript to execute in selenium-webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium-webdriver in nodeJS not Java.

I'm using `this.getPageSource()` which return HTML but it doesn't wait for javascript to execute so I don't see some elements in dom which are loaded by JS.

How to wait for javascript execution?

Comment: Please check following SO.See if this help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720325/selenium-webdriver-wait-for-complex-page-with-javascript-to-load

Comment: I've already seen it but it's about selenium in java. I'm using javascript (node) selenium-webdriver

Comment: How is question about javascript selenium-webdriver duplicate of question about java selenium?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
wait.until( 
    new Predicate<WebDriver>() {
        public boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            return ((JavascriptExecutor)driver)
                    .executeScript("return document.readyState")
                    .equals("complete");
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: Is this code javascript? I'm using javascript selenium-webdriver. If yes - what is Predicate class? I'm not importing such thing.

Comment: But it more look like java