# Selenium web driver - Waiting within loop (Java)

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

I have seen a lot of methods ([such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720325/selenium-webdriver-wait-for-complex-page-with-javascript-to-load)) on waiting for Selenium Web driver (specifically for Java). However, applying the methods here do not seem to be working.

I am attempting to test user queries results by looping through values in a hash table. I have tried two ways in the code below: to wait for document.readyState and for loading of items selected by class. However, it seems as though the list is creating with all without leaving the time for element refresh to complete.

```
package newproject;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
//import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class MyClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/Users/niunani/Selenium/geckodriver");
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

  String baseUrl = "https://www.zillow.com/san-diego-ca-92109/";

  //get price button and click
  WebElement priceButton = driver.findElement(By.id("price"));
  priceText = priceButton.getText();
  System.out.println(priceText);
  //priceButton.click();

  Map<String, List<String>> priceTestCases = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

  List<String> threeHundThouSet = new ArrayList<String>();
  threeHundThouSet.add("400000");
  threeHundThouSet.add("500000");
  threeHundThouSet.add("600000");
  threeHundThouSet.add("700000");
  threeHundThouSet.add("800000");
  threeHundThouSet.add("900000");
  threeHundThouSet.add("1000000");

  List<String> fourHundThouSet = new ArrayList<String>();
  fourHundThouSet.add("500000");
  fourHundThouSet.add("600000");
  fourHundThouSet.add("700000");
  fourHundThouSet.add("800000");
  fourHundThouSet.add("900000");
  fourHundThouSet.add("1000000");

  List<String> fiveHundThouSet = new ArrayList<String>();
  fiveHundThouSet.add("600000");
  fiveHundThouSet.add("700000");
  fiveHundThouSet.add("800000");
  fiveHundThouSet.add("900000");
  fiveHundThouSet.add("1000000");

  priceTestCases.put("300000", threeHundThouSet);
  priceTestCases.put("400000", fourHundThouSet);
  priceTestCases.put("500000", fiveHundThouSet);

  WebElement priceExposedMin = driver.findElement(By.id("price-exposed-min"));

  WebElement priceExposedMax = driver.findElement(By.id("price-exposed-max"));

  WebElement priceDoneButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[6]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/button"));

  priceButton.click();
  for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : priceTestCases.entrySet()) {
      String key = entry.getKey();
      List<String> values = entry.getValue();
      System.out.println("Key = " + key);
      System.out.println("Values = " + values + "n");
      //priceExposedMin.clear();
      for (int i=0;i<20;i++) {
          priceExposedMin.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE);
      }
      priceExposedMin.sendKeys(key);
      for (String maxPrice : values) {
          System.out.println(maxPrice);
          //priceExposedMax.clear();
          //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"price-exposed-max\"]"))).clear();
          for (int i=0;i<20;i++) {
              priceExposedMax.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE);
          }
          priceExposedMax.sendKeys(maxPrice);
          priceDoneButton.click();

          //ONE WAY: wait for document.readyState
          new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
                  webDriver -> ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"));

          //SECOND WAY: Wait for 30 sec until AJAX search load the content
          //new WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.className("list-card-price")));

          Integer countWrong = 0;
          List<WebElement> returnPrices = driver.findElements(By.className("list-card-price"));
          System.out.println(returnPrices);
          for (WebElement priceElement : returnPrices) {
              String priceString = priceElement.getText();
              priceString = priceString.replace("Est. $", "");
              priceString = priceString.replace("$", "");
              priceString = priceString.replace(",", "");
              Integer price = Integer.parseInt(priceString);
              if (price > Integer.parseInt(maxPrice)) {
                  countWrong++;
                  System.out.println("Over price : " + Integer.toString(price));
              }
              System.out.println("This price : " + Integer.toString(price));

          }
          System.out.println("Incorrect query result: " + Integer.toString(countWrong)) ;
          priceButton.click();
      }
  }

  }
}
```

I sometimes have the following error, which may actually be when the elements update. I'm looking for a solution that will work around this:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: The element reference of <div class="list-card-price"> is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'Nhus-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:27:7d6f:961a:384a%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14', java.version: '1.8.0_221'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 70.0.1, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:buildID: 20191030021342, moz:geckodriverVersion: 0.26.0, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 9634, moz:profile: /var/folders/8c/whfw1mpd5tq..., moz:shutdownTimeout: 60000, moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, platformVersion: 18.0.0, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: b93bceb8-123a-b546-8743-5c402cd8b341
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:285)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.isDisplayed(RemoteWebElement.java:326)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$8.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:233)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$8.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:228)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:249)
    at newproject.MyClass.main(MyClass.java:110)
```

My current workaround is quite ugly and makes the test take probably too long:

```
package newproject;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
//import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class MyClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/Users/niunani/Selenium/geckodriver");
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

  String baseUrl = "https://www.zillow.com/san-diego-ca-92109/";
  String tagName = "";
  String titleText = "";
  String priceText = "";

  //search title
  driver.get(baseUrl);
  WebElement searchTitle = driver.findElement(By.className("search-title"));
  tagName = searchTitle.getTagName();
  System.out.println(tagName);
  titleText = searchTitle.getText();
  System.out.println(titleText);

  //get price button and click
  WebElement priceButton = driver.findElement(By.id("price"));
  priceText = priceButton.getText();
  System.out.println(priceText);
  //priceButton.click();

  Map<String, List<String>> priceTestCases = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

  List<String> threeHundThouSet = new ArrayList<String>();
  threeHundThouSet.add("400000");
  threeHundThouSet.add("500000");
  threeHundThouSet.add("600000");
  threeHundThouSet.add("700000");
  threeHundThouSet.add("800000");
  threeHundThouSet.add("900000");
  threeHundThouSet.add("1000000");

  List<String> fourHundThouSet = new ArrayList<String>();
  fourHundThouSet.add("500000");
  fourHundThouSet.add("600000");
  fourHundThouSet.add("700000");
  fourHundThouSet.add("800000");
  fourHundThouSet.add("900000");
  fourHundThouSet.add("1000000");

  List<String> fiveHundThouSet = new ArrayList<String>();
  fiveHundThouSet.add("600000");
  fiveHundThouSet.add("700000");
  fiveHundThouSet.add("800000");
  fiveHundThouSet.add("900000");
  fiveHundThouSet.add("1000000");

  priceTestCases.put("300000", threeHundThouSet);
  priceTestCases.put("400000", fourHundThouSet);
  priceTestCases.put("500000", fiveHundThouSet);

  WebElement priceExposedMin = driver.findElement(By.id("price-exposed-min"));
  //priceExposedMin.clear();
  //priceExposedMin.sendKeys("300000");

  WebElement priceExposedMax = driver.findElement(By.id("price-exposed-max"));
  //WebElement priceExposedMax = wait.until(
//        ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("price-exposed-max")));
  //WebElement priceExposedMax = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(driver.findElement(By.id("price-exposed-max"))));
  //priceExposedMax.clear();
  //priceExposedMax.sendKeys("500000");

  WebElement priceDoneButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[6]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/button"));

  priceButton.click();
  for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : priceTestCases.entrySet()) {
      String key = entry.getKey();
      List<String> values = entry.getValue();
      System.out.println("Key = " + key);
      System.out.println("Values = " + values + "n");
      //priceExposedMin.clear();
      for (int i=0;i<20;i++) {
          priceExposedMin.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE);
      }
      priceExposedMin.sendKeys(key);
      for (String maxPrice : values) {
          System.out.println(maxPrice);
          //priceExposedMax.clear();
          //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"price-exposed-max\"]"))).clear();
          for (int i=0;i<20;i++) {
              priceExposedMax.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE);
          }
          priceExposedMax.sendKeys(maxPrice);
          priceDoneButton.click();

          //wait for document.readyState
          //new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            //      webDriver -> ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"));

          //Wait for 30 sec until AJAX search load the content
          new WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.className("list-card-price")));
          //new WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("ul > li.closed")));

          int timeToWait = 10; //second
          try {
              for (int i=0; i<timeToWait ; i++) {
                  Thread.sleep(2000);
              }
          } catch (InterruptedException ie)
          {
              Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
          }

          Integer countWrong = 0;

          boolean result = false;
          int attempts = 0;
          while (attempts < 2) {
              try {
                  List<WebElement> returnPrices = driver.findElements(By.className("list-card-price"));
                  System.out.println(returnPrices);
                  for (WebElement priceElement : returnPrices) {
                      String priceString = priceElement.getText();
                      priceString = priceString.replace("Est. $", "");
                      priceString = priceString.replace("$", "");
                      priceString = priceString.replace(",", "");
                      Integer price = Integer.parseInt(priceString);
                      if (price > Integer.parseInt(maxPrice)) {
                          countWrong++;
                          System.out.println("Over price : " + Integer.toString(price));
                      }
                      System.out.println("This price : " + Integer.toString(price));

                  }
                  System.out.println("Incorrect query result: " + Integer.toString(countWrong)) ;
                  priceButton.click();
                  result = true;
                  break;
              } catch(StaleElementReferenceException e) {
              }
              attempts++;
          }

      }
  }

  //driver.close();
  //System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]. Note the part about shortest code... a lot of the code you have included isn't related. Trim it down to just what is needed to reproduce the issue, edit your question, and add only that code.

Answer (score 0):

If you write the code using reusables, then it will be more easy to understand and not looks ugly.Try to small reusables and then combine those to test the functionality